# Slow Internet access on iPhone SE after updating to iOS 11.4?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I am upgraded to iOS 11.4 on iPhone SE and have noticed it seems to have terribly slow internet access since the update. Toggling Wi-Fi will speed up each individual request (Web, Twitter, other apps), but after each complete request, it apparently loses its Internet connectivity again.

Note the Wi-Fi symbol always shows connected; however on my router status page the iPhone shows as no IP4 address assigned. It still does show with an IP6 address on the router. Toggling Wi-Fi switch on iPhone will reassign the IP4 one, too. It’s as though it forgets its IP4 after each transaction.

Note that neither the wife’s iPhone SE (identical except still on iOS 11.3) nor the iPad (also on iOS 11.3) show the same behaviour, so I reckon it’s not the router or infrastructure per se.

Troubleshooting tried so far, each giving a brief respite before trouble reoccurred:

- iPhone reboot
- Router reboot
- iPhone and router reboot
- Reducing MTU on IP6 network
- Assigning fixed IP4 address
- Reset network settings on iPhone (urgh)

Next step would be complete iPhone reset, but I would really like to avoid that one. Or of course a rollback to 11.3.1.

Is anybody observing similar issues? And, more importantly, does anyone have a fix, please (if possible, other than: use mobile data, wait for iOS 11.4.1 or iOS 12, buy new iPhone, buy Android phone)?

Comment: Further to the initial post, I have downgraded to 11.3.1 to restore connectivity, and that has resolved the issue - pointing to 11.4 as the culprit.

Comment: I am having the same problem! I thought it was my router but my MacBook is connected to the internet and isn't giving me any issues. I also have an iPhone SE.